# escaping sqlite results

Tags: python, sqlite, escaping

Given the following input string:

```
(?i:\bsys\.user_catalog\b)
```

Stored into sqlite  `TEXT` field. When retrieved with select, I get the following:

When doing simple command line, e.g.

```
$ sqlite3 databse.name "select a from b" > file.results
```

It appear in the editor like this:

[image: a screenshot of the editor]

When I use, python's sqlite3 lib, it prints out as:

```
(?i:\x08sys\\.user_catalog\x08)
```

Questions are:

1. Will switching to `BLOB`, will solve this for me?
2. Is there a way to stay `TEXT` and still get it done right.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

- Make sure the string was originally input as raw so that the escaping doesn't take place before you store it.
- I think TEXT will work as well as BLOB but you may have to confirm by experiment.
- Store as a *buffer* object:  `c.execute('INSERT INTO documents VALUES (?, ?)', (somekey, buffer(yourstring)))`

Comment: ensuring the input is inserted as raw (e.g. `r'''INPUT'''`) did the job, no need for blobing and such. apparently, input was escaped by sqlobject lib.